# Views pages isn't shown while working with routeProvider in angularJs for eclipse

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angularjs, route-provider, ng-view

I went over the AngularJs for eclipse https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started and every example i made worked just fine as with controllers and other cool stuff, until i tried this example of routeProvider.

The view page is not shown when i open index.html so i tried couple of things i saw in other questions asked before around this subject.

in the placeholder for views i tried:

```
<div ng-view></div>
<div data-ng-view></div>
<div ng-view=""></div>
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

i also added:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

and:

```
'ngRoute' in 
var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

also - is it possible to debug my code when i'm working on angularJs in eclipse and open an html file with web browser?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demoApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="scripts/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <title>Angular</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-ng-view></div>

    <script>

        var demoApp = angular.module("demoApp", ['ngRoute']);

        demoApp.config(function($routeProvider){

            $routeProvider
                .when('/',
                {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/View1.html'
                })
                .when('/view2',
                {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: 'partials/View2.html'
                })
                .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
        });

        demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){
            $scope.customers = [

                { name: 'John', city: 'NY' },
                { name: 'Smith', city: 'LA' },
                { name: 'John', city: 'NJ' }

            ];

            $scope.addCustomer = function(){
                $scope.customers.push(
                    { 
                        name: $scope.newCustomer.name, 
                        city: $scope.newCustomer.city
                    });
            };
        });

    </script>
</body>
```